# backup & restore remote Informix database

Tags: backup, informix, restore

I am trying to take backup of informix database from my client server and restore into my local informix server but I did not get success.

I used dbexport and dbimport utility but i did not found any parameter to give remote machine ip(like in MySQL -h xxx,xx,xx).

I also took backup of remote database using RazorSQL tool but i don't know how to restore it.

Is there any other way to do this then please share it here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using DB-Export and DB-Import is probably not the best way to do backups.  And they don't provide a direct mechanism to write to a remote file system.

You should look at ON-Tape or ON-BAR if you need remote backups.  They also provide advantages such as backing up the entire server while the server is busy (and ensuring that the backup is coherent as of the time of the backup checkpoint), and there are options for point-in-time restore, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have remote access to your client's machine, you might use the [ifxclone](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.adref.doc/ids_adr_1093.htm?lang=en) utility or make a [backup/restore pipeline using ontape](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.bar.doc/ids_bar_049.htm?lang=en).

Without the remote access, you can make an ontape backup to a local directory, move the files and restore the same way.